# Get the value from a json object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying get a specific value from a json object that is returned from a request. But the sintax that I'm using is not working. The value returned is `undefined`. How can I get the value of the key `name` in json object?

The response is store in costumer variable.

```
$http.get('url').
   then(function successCallback(response){
        var costumers = response;
        console.log(costumers['data']['costumers']['name']);
    }, function errorCallback(response){

});
```

Json object

```
{data: "{"costumers":[{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Mary"}]}"}
```

Comment: `costumers['data']['costumers'][0]['name']`

Comment: The above comment is correct, or you could dispense with all the unnecessary quotes and just use `costumers.data.costumers[0].name`.  (Fighting urge to comment about "json object")

Comment: So your data example is not syntactically valid... can you give the real example? And is it in string form or did you already parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customers` is an array, to access array elements you need to write the index into square brackets behind it. In this case, if you want to access the first element (index 0) of the array, you can do that like so:

```
$http.get('url').
then(function successCallback(response){
    var costumers = response;
    console.log(costumers['data']['costumers'][0]['name']);
}, function errorCallback(response){

});
```

Or log all customers by using a for loop:

```
$http.get('url').
then(function successCallback(response){
    var costumers = response;
    for(let customer of costumers['data']['costumers']) {
        console.log(customer['name']);
    }
}, function errorCallback(response){

});
```

All of this only works if the object is syntactically correct, it should look like this:

```
{data: {costumers:[{id:"1",name:"John"},{id:"2",name:"Mary"}]}}
```

Instead of the object you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The `costumers` in your case is an array of objects, so you have to specify the index of the object you want to target to get the values from, example :

```
costumers['data']['costumers'][0]['name']
______________________________^^^
```

The `0` index will return the first object :

```
{"id":"1","name":"John"}
```

You could always loop through all the objects of `costumers`, and you can check if the returned object has the 'attribute' you want like :

```
if( costumers['data']['costumers'][0].hasOwnProperty('name') ){
    console.log( costumers['data']['costumers'][0]['name'] );
}
```